# How activate Privatemsg Module to all users?

Tags: 6, privatemsg

I just enabled the [Privatemsg](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) Module in my Drupal 6. I would like to enable this module to all users, who join in the website. But the registered users cannot see the **"Write new message and Messages"** link.

Why the  Privatemsg is not active in users section ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change permissions for the *Privatemsg* module for *authenticated users* or whatever role you want in the permissions page(*admin/user/permissions*)

See http://drupal.org/getting-started/6/admin/user/permissions

Answer (score 0):

In case you're talking about the local task in the user profile, that is meant for administrative purpose only (read all private messages permission).

The Privatemsg pages reside below /messages, a link to that page should have been added to the Navigation menu.

Privatemsg 6.x-2.x does allow to move it to the user profile by setting the url prefix in the settings to "user/%user/something".